# Property 'Sizes' does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript

**when i save sizes array that in  categoryItem object in a separate array, it tells me that "Property 'Sizes' does not exist on type 'object'."**

```
 export class ChoicesComponent implements OnInit {

  categoryItem:object;
  choiceGroups :any [] = [];
  sizes:any [] = [];
  
  constructor(public _interactionService:InteractionService, public router: Router) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    debugger
    this.categoryItem = this._interactionService.getCategoryItemData();
     this.sizes = this.categoryItem.Sizes;
   // this.itemSizes = this.categoryItem.Sizes;
  }

}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class InteractionService {
  categoryItemData:any;

  constructor() { }

  public getCategoryItemData(){
    return this.categoryItemData;
  }

  public setategoryItemData(data){
    this.categoryItemData = data;
  }
  
}
```

note that this.categoryItem includes array named Sizes. like

```
     this.categoryItem = {
      "Sizes":[]
     }
```

Comment: when do you call `setategoryItemData` ? Seems like you try to access `Sizes` before it is defined. your couild set `categoryItemData = {Sizes: []};` in your service.

Comment: You should use subscription to the data specially if you are loading data from the API into your service.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have define your `categoryItem` to be object your linter doesn't know that sizes as a key exist in that object. For accessing the value using dot notation explicitly define all the keys of the object or you can use `any` type but that is not a good idea